# How do I export "user" object from my TopBar.js to App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

TopBar.js is basically an AppBar component which handles authentication, if a user logs in, I get an object "user", how do I export this "user" object to App.js?

If I manage to export this to App.js, I would like to export it to another component create which can handle adding stuff to my db

I am using React and Firebase

This is my useEffect function

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
    if (authUser) {
      // if user has logged in...
      setUser(authUser)
      if(authUser.displayName){   }
      else{
        return authUser.updateProfile({
          displayName : userName
        });
      }
      
    } else {
      // if user has logged out... 
      setUser(null);
    }
    
  })
  return () => {
    // perform some cleanup actions
    unsubscribe();
  }
}, [user, userName]);
```

Comment: You should create a context.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Like I understand that context can be used to make a hierarchy, but I am confused with implementation part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `App.js` file, you could create a context that handles this. In that case you have:

```
const AuthContext = createContext();
```

This can now be used to wrap the whole app using the Provider component like so:

```
// the user value comes from the state created
<AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>
  
</AuthContext.Provider>
```

Then you can access this user value from any component using `useContext` hook:

```
const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

// you can go on and access the `user` value anywhere in the component
```

you can visit [this article](https://dev.to/dancurtis/learn-to-usecontext-with-hooks-in-3-minutes-4c4g) explaining it in-depth

Comment: Is there any way to use it for passing prop of the child to the parent? In this case, TopBar is my child component of App.js
I don't think so using useContext would make sense here...

Comment: You can also pass the setUser function into the provider value alongside user. That way you can access setUser in the child component and use it anywhere in the app including the parent component.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to figure this out on my own, I am storing this retrieved user in a useState, and whenever I redirect to a page called /create, it's state becomes null and I get an error, should I try using useContext in this scenario?

Comment: Yes sure, that's a good use case for useContext